# Java Call Array from another Class

Tags: java

I need help with this question, can anyone teach me how can I print out the array of Actor[] from the class ActorAll[] at the main method? I am able to print from the Actor() class but unable to do so from ActorAll() due to reasons I do not know, it is greatly appreciated if someone can help me.

```
public class Actor {
private String fName;
private String lName;

public Actor(String f,String l){
    setfName(f);
    setlName(l);
}

public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}
public String displayMessage(){
    return String.format("%s %s", getfName(),getlName());
}
```

}

```
public class ActorAll extends Actor{
private Actor[]actor;

public ActorAll(Actor[] actor){
    setActor(actor);
}

public Actor[] getActor() {
    return actor;
}

public void setActor(Actor[] actor) {
    this.actor = actor;
}

public String displayMessage(){
    return String.format("%s ", getActor());
}
```

}

```
public class ActorAllTest {

static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Actor actor;

    actor=addContact();
    System.out.println(actor.displayMessage());
}
public static Actor addContact(){
    String fName=sc.next();
    String lName=sc.next();
    Actor actor = new Actor(fName,lName);
    return actor;
}
```

}

Comment: Please include output (exception, compilation message etc).

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the `actor[]` from ActorAll, you need to create an `ActorAll` dynamic type object and call `displayMessage` on that object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Actor actor = new ActorAll();

    actor=addContact();
    System.out.println(actor.displayMessage());
}
```